# Wordpress with Lan and Wan Access?

Tags: multisite, configuration

Can someone suggest tutorials on how to properly set up a wordpress multisite installation that I can access from both the LAN and WAN side?  I've been looking for a bit and am unable to find what i'm looking for.
  I'm using an Ubuntu server (on VirtualBox) behind my router.  I have my domain name setup to forward to my router and it is port forwarding properly.  But, what I really want to do is have my site (locally hosted) be accessible from the LAN as well as the WAN.  Right now it's one or the other based on how I play with the dashboard>options panel... I don't mind reinstalling if it means having a proper setup.

Comment: Please provide more details and what settings in WP affect this. In current form this looks more like network configuration issue than WordPress one.

Answer (score 1):

For LAN access add the following to the /etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.0.10 (ip of WordPress server) domain.com
```

or

```
localhost domain.com
```

if the server is on the same machine

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `local loopback` (or simply `loopback`) is enabled in the network options of your router.

Or if you are using your router for DNS, you can alternatively set up a DNS entry with your serverslocal IP for the domain.